# Would it be OK to crosspost an identification question from the SF&F SE that has not received any answers for years?

Tags: discussion

My family's first computer was a TRS-80 Color Computer 2. We later acquired a CoCo 3. I've had some luck in getting game identification questions answered on the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange, but [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225590/tandy-coco-2-game-involving-managing-a-set-of-shops-in-a-fantasy-world) seems to have stumped people. I suspect that part of the problem is that, based on my memories of being able to access the game's BASIC source code, it was likely a hobby program one of my siblings inputted, possibly from *Rainbow* magazine. In general, SE disapproves of cross-posting, but this is an older question, and I suspect that this group is more likely to recognize it, since they might have inputted the source code themselves.

So, would it be alright for me to cross-post this question?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why not.

We have a number of *identify-this-* tags, so the subject is on-topic. Whether the community here is any better at getting an answer remains to be seen, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Make sure to keep both questions up to date, though. (Have each link to the other _at least_ in the comments; if one gets answered correctly, consider self-answering the other; etc.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 maybe close the unanswered one as a duplicate of the answered one? so no info-duplications?

Comment: Generally speaking cross-posts are frowned upon on SE, so it seems to me it would be better to close the other one.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy We can't (yet) close questions as cross-site duplicates. Technically the software supports it via old-style duplicates, but you need to be a high-rep user / moderator to make those, and even then the website's UI doesn't let you. Regular closure might make sense, though? I'm not sure what close reason you'd use.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I haven't saw a question being closed as a duplicate in another site, but a bug report (a question tagged with [bug]) being posted in Meta.SE and Meta.SO, only a answer was posted on the Meta.SE one and a link to that answer was posted in them Meta.SO post, to avoid information duplication.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy Oh, yeah, that's what I meant. A link, plus enough of a quotation to stop it being a link-only answer (so people don't _have_ to follow the link to get the answer to the question).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 exactly.